# Issues with joining my model

Tags: modeling

I'm done designing my model and I'm trying to join all of it together so that I can go ahead to rig. But when I select all and click join, it doesn't work.[image]

[image]

Comment: Ctrl J to join, also before joining make sure that you apply some modifiers like the Mirror modifiers (don't apply the Subdivision Surface modifier)

Comment: It worked. Thank you

Comment: @moonboots please add this as the answer so that this question will be removed from the unanswered list.

Answer (score 2):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> to join, also before joining make sure that you apply some modifiers like the *Mirror* modifiers, otherwise the object you join will inherite the modifiers of the active object to which you join (but don't apply the *Subdivision Surface* modifier).